# Dual Monitors Stayed Mirrored

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I am running a T450 with Intel HD Graphics 5500 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I am also using a Lenovo Ultra Dock that supports a DVI input and a VGA input.

Whenever I connect two monitors to both the DVI and VGA to my dock, and when I dock my T450, the monitors are only mirroring one monitor. Ubuntu isn't even recognizing the other monitor in "Displays", but it is still mirroring everything from the opposite monitor. The monitor is working, I am seeing a picture, but "Displays" isn't allowing me to control anything.

Any ideas?
Thank you so much!

Edit: I think it would be nice to know, that the monitors are of the same model/brand.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth a shot to upgrade your kernel to 3.17 [as a user reported](http://airlied.livejournal.com/79657.html) he was then able to get his dual monitors fixed with his T440P which also used Intel graphics.